# TwoWay binding not working with datepicker MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datepicker, entity

I've finally managed to get started with MVVM and implementing INotifyPropertyChanged and I am facing the following problem: Even though I pass the month from my datepicker as a parameter to my query, the result of my query doesn't change if I choose a different month.

I was hoping INotifyPropertyChanged would take care of that. How do I make sure that my Efficiency changes when picking a different month from the datepicker?

Thank you

**ViewModel**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Location.Model;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Location.ViewModel
{
    public class LocationViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {


        public LocationViewModel()
        {
            var month = 0;
            int.TryParse(MDate.ToString("MM"), out month);
            var db = new DailyEntities();
            Efficiency = Convert.ToDecimal(db.LocationKPI.Where(a => a.sMonth == month).Select(a => a.Efficiency).FirstOrDefault());
        }

        private DateTime _mDate = DateTime.Now;

        public DateTime MDate
        {
            get { return _mDate; }
            set { _mDate = value; OnPropertyChanged("MDate"); }
        }

        decimal efficiency;

        public decimal Efficiency
        {
            get { return efficiency; }
            set
            {
                efficiency = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Efficiency");
            }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

**View**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new LocationViewModel();
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<DatePicker x:Name="vDatePick" SelectedDateChanged="vDatePick_SelectedDateChanged" SelectedDate="{Binding MDate, Mode=TwoWay}" Text="Pick date"/>
```

Comment: You have code behind on a MVVM app? `SelectedDateChanged="vDatePick_SelectedDateChanged"`

Comment: You are right and it's really bad practice. I've just started to transition to MVVM and it's just a left over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it isn't working is because in your ViewModel, you are only executing the code to set the efficiency in the constructor.  You need to create a method and then call it from the constructor and the set of MDate, so Efficiency will be updated each time MDate changes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Location.Model;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Location.ViewModel
{
    public class LocationViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public LocationViewModel()
        {
            SetEfficiency();
        }

        private DateTime _mDate = DateTime.Now;

        public DateTime MDate
        {
            get { return _mDate; }
            set 
            {
                _mDate = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("MDate");
                SetEfficiency();
            }
        }

        decimal efficiency;

        public decimal Efficiency
        {
            get { return efficiency; }
            set
            {
                efficiency = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Efficiency");
            }
        }

        DailyEntities db = new DailyEntities();

        private void SetEfficiency()
        {
            var month;
            int.TryParse(MDate.ToString("MM"), out month);
            Efficiency = Convert.ToDecimal(db.LocationKPI.Where(a => a.sMonth == month).Select(a => a.Efficiency).FirstOrDefault());
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: DSway, hats off to you! This is exactly what I was looking for: a complete, straightforward and simple to understand example. You saved my weekend and I owe you a cold one. Thank you so much! You are the man!!!

Answer (score 1):

You need state that `Efficiency` must be updated when `MDate` is

```
public DateTime MDate
{
   get { return _mDate; }
   set 
   { 
       _mDate = value; 
       OnPropertyChanged("MDate"); 
       OnPropertyChanged("Efficiency"); 
   }
}
```

I would also put the query for `Efficiency` in the getter and remove the setter. Which in turn would mean you no longer need the private variable `efficiency` and you would remove the query in the constructor.

```
public decimal Efficiency
{
    get 
    {
        var month = 0;
        int.TryParse(MDate.ToString("MM"), out month);
        return Convert.ToDecimal(
            db.LocationKPI
                .Where(a => a.sMonth == month)
                .Select(a => a.Efficiency)
                .FirstOrDefault());
    }
}
```

EDIT: Updated `Efficiency` getter and setter

EDIT: Wanted to note you should probably set `MDate` to a default value in your constructor as well if you wanted to see results when the page loads.

Comment: Thank you so much David! As a rookie, I've learned a lot from your example. I truly appreciate your time. Have a wonderful weekend!